# Spaced horizontal line in align environment

Tags: align

I am trying to typeset a type derivation tree.

```
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*{\stext}[1]{\text{ #1 }}
\newcommand*{\sd}[1]{\rule[-#1]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}


\begin{align*}
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y): num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num \qquad & T \vartriangleright{} 1 : num \sd{2ex} \\
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y)\, 1: num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num \qquad & T \vartriangleright{} 5 : num \sd{2ex} \\
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y)\, 1\enskip 5: num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num
\end{align*}
```

The result does not look good:

[image: line alignment wrong]

What I actually want is something like this:

[image]

Note that:

1. The bottom line is centered with respect to the other lines in the environment
2. The horizontal dividing lines are nicely spaced (veritcally), start on the LHS and are the correct width

I've also tried an approach using `\hline`, but the spacing is unacceptable:

[image]

```
\newcommand*{\sd}{\hline}
\begin{align*}
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y): num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num \qquad & T \vartriangleright{} 1 : num \\ \sd
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y)\, 1: num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num \qquad & T \vartriangleright{} 5 : num \\ \sd
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y)\, 1\enskip 5: num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num
\end{align*}
```

Is there a better approach? Is `align` even the correct environment to use here?

Comment: Since `align` is defined in `amsmath`, this isn't going to work at all with that package commented out.

Comment: Yes, indeed :P I figured it was fairly obvious that was supposed to go in the preamble, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you change your `\sd` command to `\newcommand*{\sd}{\\[-10pt]\hline\\[-10pt]}`?

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\sd}{\\[-10pt]\hline\\[-10pt]}
\begin{align*}
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y): num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num \qquad & T \vartriangleright{} 1 : num \\ \sd
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y)\, 1: num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num \qquad & T \vartriangleright{} 5 : num \\ \sd
    T \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y)\, 1\enskip 5: num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works? I thought the \\ argument specified additional extra space before the next line, so why is it negative in this case?

Comment: Sure, so the \\ will create some space and the `[-10pt]` will take away from that space 10pt. Basically, you make too much extra space and then take away 10pt from it.

Comment: Ah, of course - that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution based on `booktabs`?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    T & \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y): num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num & \quad & T \vartriangleright{} 1 : \\[-1.5ex]
    \cmidrule{1-4}
    T & \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y)\, 1: num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num & \quad & T \vartriangleright{} 5 : \\[-1.5ex]
    \cmidrule{1-4}
    T & \vartriangleright{} (\lambda x: num.\, \lambda y: num.\, x+y)\, 1\enskip 5: num \rightarrow num \rightarrow num
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]